# EOF statement in bash script doesn't execute in an IF statement

Tags: bash, shell-script

Wondering what is wrong with my syntax.

Running this bash script works as expected and all of the commands are executed:

```bsh
sftp -i ~/.ssh/my_private_key $username@$host <<EOF
lcd /home/documents
get *
bye
EOF
```

Trying to throw the EOF inside of an IF, however, makes it not execute:

```bsh
sftp -i ~/.ssh/my_private_key $username@$host

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "SFTP connection failed to establish."
    exit 10
else <<-EOF
    lcd /home/documents
    get *
    bye
    EOF
    echo "Files moved and connection closed."
fi

exit 0
```

All that happens is I see the "Connected to $host" message in terminal, and then it waits for input. If I type any commands like `ls` or `pwd` they execute, and finally typing `bye` closes the connection and prints `"Connection closed."`, but none of the commands inside EOF execute at any point.

Comment: `if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then` should be `if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then`

Comment: @guillermochamorro The script behaves exactly the same with that change.

Comment: I was just pointing out that for arithmetic comparisons you have to use `-ne,-eq,-lt` etc, for string comparisons you use `=,!=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirection should be applied to the `sftp` command, so the `if`  should look something like:

```
if sftp -i ~/.ssh/my_private_key $username@$host  <<-EOF
lcd /home/documents
get *
bye
EOF
then
    echo "Files moved and connection closed."
else
    echo "SFTP connection failed to establish."
    exit 10
fi
```

After all, if the connection failed to get established, it doesn't matter if the commands are sent or not, so send them anyway.

Comment: Also, the test on `$?` tests the exit status of `sftp`, which is only defined *after `sftp` exits*. After it’s exited, it’s too late to send it input.

Comment: Can the status of `sftp` be tested without exiting it?

Comment: By definition, the exit status is returned after exiting.